# Error in making POST request to django API

Tags: python, json, django, django-rest-framework

From post man, I'm trying to make POST request to an order API created using django restframework but I'm getting the following error:

```
 product = Product.objects.get(id=i['product'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

The specific point where the error is located is specified in the error but I find difficulty constructing VALID json for the request body.
Here is how I'm making the request on postman:

```
{
    "orderItems":{
        "product": {"name":"abc", "brand":"def", "image"www.example.com/img", "description":"xyz", "price":"50"},
        "qty":"2",
        "price":"200"
    },
    "shippingAddress": {
        "address":"abc", "city":"B", "postalCode":"12345",
    },
    
    "paymentMethod":"monify",
    "itemPrice":"100"
}
```

Here is the program:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=Categories.choices, default=Categories.medications)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="user_product", null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    brand = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="brand")
    productClass = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/products/")
    label = models.CharField(max_length=254, default='', blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)


class Order(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="user_order", null=True)
    paymentMethod = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    dateCreated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.dateCreated)

models.py
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    image = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    qty = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

The view I', trying to test is shown below:

```
def addOrderItems(request):
    user = request.user
    data = request.data

    orderItems = data['orderItems']

    if orderItems and len(orderItems) == 0:
        return Response({'detail': 'Order item was not provided'}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:

        # Step 1: Create order

        order = Order.objects.create(
            user=user,
            paymentMethod=data['paymentMethod'],
        )

        #Step 2: Create shipping address

        shipping = ShippingAddress.objects.create(
            order=order,
            address=data['shippingAddress']['address'],
        )

        # Step 3: Create order items, then set order to orderItem relationship
        for i in orderItems:
            product = Product.objects.get(id=i['product'])

            item = OrderItem.objects.create(
                product=product,
                order=order,
                name=product.name,
                qty=i['qty'],
                price=i['price'],
                image=product.image.url,
            )

            # Step 4: Update stock
            product.countInStock -= item.qty
            product.save()

        serializer = OrderSerializer(order, many=False)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

Any hint on this is well appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the payload is not correct. Now the whole product data is uploaded, but it should be changed into the `product_id`. Because in the view, it is being considered as the id field like `Product.objects.get(id=i['product'])`.

So the solution is like the following.
First, the payload should be changed.

```
{
    "orderItems":[{
        "product_id": 3,  // here I changed 
        "qty":"2",
        "price":"200"
    }],
    "shippingAddress": {
        "address":"abc", "city":"B", "postalCode":"12345",
    },
    
    "paymentMethod":"monify",
    "itemPrice":"100"
}
```

And in the `addOrderItems` function,

```
def addOrderItems(request):
    ...
    if orderItems and len(orderItems) == 0:
        ...
    else:
        ...
        
        # Step 3: Create order items, then set order to orderItem relationship
        for i in orderItems:
            product = Product.objects.get(id=i['product_id'])
            ...
```

Comment: Thank you @Davamid Lu. After implementing your suggestion I'm getting another error ` Product matching query does not exist` , here it's making reference to the Product model

Comment: Also, at this point when I make the API request the Order and Shipping address models info appear in the database correctly but the OrderItem info is not showing up in the database. In my models.py file I have four Models Product, OrderItem and Order and ShippingAddress respectively. Please I will be grateful if you help me to identify something else I'm doing wrong

Comment: Did you use `orderItem` like the object in the payload?

Comment: No, I used the plural form, that is `OrderItems`

Answer (score 0):

Your JSON is invalid (the "image" key in "orderItems" was messed up). To check this, you can use an online tool like https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/.

Moreover, from the way you are iterating over it, orderItems should contain a list.

Here is the corrected JSON:

```json
{
    "orderItems": [{
        "product": {"name":"abc", "brand":"def", "image": "www.example.com/img", "description":"xyz", "price":"50"},
        "qty":"2",
        "price":"200"
    }],
    "shippingAddress": {
        "address":"abc", "city":"B", "postalCode":"12345",
    },
    
    "paymentMethod":"monify",
    "itemPrice":"100"
}
```

In your Product model, you should also add an ID as PrimaryKey to be able to retrieve it later in your view:

```py
import uuid

class Product(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    # ... (all your other attributes)
```

The JSON will then include this product ID:

```json
{
    "orderItems": [{
        "product": {"id": "9b84820b-1b4f-43a2-b576-14c3e1635906", "name":"abc", "brand":"def", "image": "www.example.com/img", "description":"xyz", "price":"50"},
        "qty":"2",
        "price":"200"
    }],
    "shippingAddress": {
        "address":"abc", "city":"B", "postalCode":"12345",
    },
    
    "paymentMethod":"monify",
    "itemPrice":"100"
}
```

Then the line `product = Product.objects.get(id=i['product'])` should be replaced with:

```py
product = Product.objects.get(id=i['product']['id'])
```

Comment: Thanks @Nicolas Perez. Even if I remove the image field the issue persists

Comment: @C-Bizz indeed, there was also another problem with the json. From the way you are iterating over it, orderItems should contain a list. I have edited my response to reflect that.

Comment: Also, `Product.objects.get(id=i['product'])` will cause a problem. Either include the product ID in the JSON, or get the Product via another attribute.

Comment: Thanks again @Nicolas Perez. Django provides ID by default that I'm utilizing so I wouldnt want to add custom Id field to the models.py. and when I add say `"id":5` to product object in the API I still get the error that the id field expected s number but got {"I'd":5, "name":"abc", "brand":"def", "image"www.example.com/img", "description":"xyz", "price":"50"}`